# How To Convert XML to python AST

Tags: python, xml, syntax, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

I hope someone can help point me to the correct resource here. I've looked around in this forum and other places but I could not quite find the right resource.
Sorry for not making my question very clear, so let me put in context with this simple example:
original source code:

```
    a='''
for x in y:
    print(x)
'''
```

the python AST tree of this code is:

```
tree_a=ast.parse(a)
```

the flat version of this tree:

```
d=ast.dump(tree_a)
```

output (content of d):

```
"Module(body=[For(target=Name(id='x', ctx=Store()), iter=Name(id='y', ctx=Load()), body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Name(id='x', ctx=Load())], keywords=[]))], orelse=[])])"
```

using this resource [Python AST to XML](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579019-python-ast-to-xml/) tree_a can be converted to an XML format:

```
res_0 = ast2xml().convert(tree_a)
with open('tree_a.xml','w') as f:
    res1=f.write(str(prettify(res_0)))
```

the content of 'tree_a.xml' is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ast>
  <Module>
    <body>
      <For col_offset="0" lineno="2">
        <Name col_offset="4" id="x" lineno="2">
          <Store/>
        </Name>
        <Name col_offset="9" id="y" lineno="2">
          <Load/>
        </Name>
        <body>
          <Expr col_offset="4" lineno="3">
            <Call col_offset="4" lineno="3">
              <Name col_offset="4" id="print" lineno="3">
                <Load/>
              </Name>
              <args>
                <Name col_offset="10" id="x" lineno="3">
                  <Load/>
                </Name>
              </args>
              <keywords/>
            </Call>
          </Expr>
        </body>
        <orelse/>
      </For>
    </body>
  </Module>
</ast>
```

Having the tree in xml format, I want to do some testing and modification on the file and return back to the python AST tree in order to see the effect on the actual source code. So my question is: Given the xml file like 'tree_a.xml' how can I convert it to a python AST tree.
my goal is to eventually return to the original source code. But that, I can do if I have the python AST tree from the xml file.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: alpha5401 did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do something similar - trying to compile and exec the string produced by your 'd=ast.dump(tree_a)'.

Answer (score 1):

Each [`ast` literal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#literals) contains a `_fields` attribute, which you can use to rebuild the original `ast` object with recursion:

```
import ast, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from itertools import zip_longest as zl
def to_ast(xml):
   if xml is None:
      return {}
   if not hasattr(ast, xml.tag):
      return [to_ast(i) for i in xml]
   return (t:=getattr(ast, xml.tag))(**(k:=xml.attrib), 
          **{a:to_ast(b) for a, b in zl([i for i in t._fields if i not in k], xml)})

xml_tree = ET.parse('tree_a.xml')
new_ast = to_ast(list(xml_tree._root)[0])
```

You can use `ast.unparse` (available in Python 3.9) to check that the new `ast` instance, created by `to_ast`, matches the original:

```
print(ast.unparse(new_ast))
```

Output:

```
for x in y: # type: {}
    print(x)
```